# Combining Text and Numerical Columns for ML Algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, feature-extraction

Here I'm working with a Sentiment Classification problem, where I have to predict whether the tweets are positive, negative or neutral. Here's a glimpse of my dataset:

```
tweet_id   airline_sentiment_confidence   negativereason   negativereason_confidence   airline   name   retweet_count   text   tweet_created   tweet location   user_timezone   airline_sentiment
Tr_tweet_1   1.000                          NaN             NaN                        Virgin America    0             tweets   date               Location        Time             Positive
Tr_tweet_2   0.3846                         NaN             0.7033                     Virgin America    0             tweets   date               Location        Time             Negative
Tr_tweet_3   0.6837                         Bad flight      0.3342                     Virgin America    0             tweets   date               Location        Time             Negative
Tr_tweet_4   1.000                          Can't tell      1.000                      Virgin America    0             tweets   date               Location        Time             Neutral   
Tr_tweet_5   1.000                          NaN             NaN                        Virgin America    0             tweets   date               Location        Time             Neutral
```

However `text` is the column which I'm fitting in my `TfIdf_Vectorizer` and using `logreg` to predict the sentiment. However I'm getting a very low accuracy of `~68%`, which turns out to be a pure NLP problem. However the other features will surely increase my accuracy if I can somehow use them.

I'm interested in knowing how can I combine the other numerical as well as textual columns like `negativereason` as features with my `text` column, to increase my accuracy.

Or is there any method of stacking that can be done here? Like combining the predictions of `Tfidf` and then once again doing prediction with rest numerical columns?

**TL;DR** How to deal with numerical as well as textual columns as features to make a good prediction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about this is, as you mentioned, is stacking. You can represent each of your tweets as a feature vector where each position in the vector represents a word/term and its value is the word's tf-idf value. Then you can concatenate each tweet's tf-idf vector with the remaining numerical columns you have and stack each of these vectors on top of each other to get a matrix (and once you have a matrix, you're all set to start trying out different machine learning models!)

A couple of notes, once you have a tf-idf vector for each tweet, it might make sense to run a dimensionality reduction algorithm such as PCA because you will be dealing with a large and sparse vector. Also, depending on your data, it might make sense to normalize each concatenated vector (e.g. make everything have values from 0-1). Finally, usually individual tweets are not rich enough in textual info. You may want to consider aggregating similar tweets together for better results.